# Java web application development process with Jenkins and Nexus

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus

In a complete development and deployment loop, these entities are involved:

- Application developers
- Source version control, i.e. Perforce or GIT
- Continuous integration system, i.e. Jenkins
- Repository manager, i.e. Nexus OSS
- Web server

How these 5 parts work together to produce a seamless development, testing, and deployment process? My understanding is below:

- Developers write code in workstation, check in/out code from/to Perforce/GIT
- Jenkins gets notified of new changes in Perforce and fetch new code from there, run testing and build
- In building the projects, Jenkins may download dependencies from Nexus
- If testing and build is successful in Jenkins, Jenkins automatically deploys the projects in the format of .jar to Nexus staging server.

From here I have some confusions as to what to do next:

- At the same time Jenkins deploys the Web application into Web server for production?
  or
- The staging project hosted in Nexus go to Web server if it gets approved within the team?

How does Nexus interact with Web server (the production server)?

Comment: I think this depends on how you set up your system. In my experience, after the tests are successfully run the project was uploaded to a deploy server used for manual testing automatically by the system (in my case Go, not Jenkins). Nexus was not involved, it was only used to download the dependencies. There was also an extra step in our pipeline where people could manually upload to another "stable" server which was for actual users.

Comment: Do you mean "Jenkins" by "deploy server"? I thought Jenkins is primarily used for testing and build.

Comment: No, I meant the web server. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569710/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-a-war-from-nexus-to-tomcat/22570720#22570720